# Javascript Check for duplicate objects in an array and merge the values into the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, merge, ecmascript-6

im struggling with an problem.

I have an array of object and it looks like this:

```
[
    {date_range_one: '2018-03-03+-+2018-05-01'},
    {date_range_two: '2001-11-27+-+2018-05-01'},
    {filter: '1'},
    {filter: '4'},
    {filter: '18'},
]
```

and i need to convert it into this:

```
[
    {date_range_one: '2018-03-03+-+2018-05-01'},
    {date_range_two: '2001-11-27+-+2018-05-01'},
    {filter: [1,3,18]},
]
```

Object.assign will override the filter values to the latest one ({filter: 18}) but i need to merge them into (Array or String).

Is the any way to do that without any js library?

Cheers

Comment: does any object contains only one property? what should happen with more than one? have you tried something?

Comment: Write a loop...

Comment: The filter values are string yet the filter values in nested array are numbers...They wouldn't overwrite each other, plus even if they were both numbers or strings, one set are in objects while the others are in an array within an object.

Comment: Yes, each object contains one property. This is an collection of url parameters, which can be a single value or an array of selected filter items. I have used this way and stacked with it:

`let URLData = window.location.search.replace(/(^\?)/, '').split('&').map(item => {
                let [key, value] = item.split('=');

                if (item.indexOf('[]') > -1) {
                    return { [key.replace(/[[\]]/g, '')]: value };
                }

                return { [key]: value };
            }).reduce((prev, curr) => Object.assign(prev, curr));`

Answer (score 3):

You could use a Map and render the collected values.

It works by using key and value of the object and sets either an array as value or the value itselft.

For getting an array of objects, a mapping takes place, where an object gets created with key and value.

```js
var data = [{ date_range_one: '2018-03-03+-+2018-05-01' }, { date_range_two: '2001-11-27+-+2018-05-01' }, { filter: '1' }, { filter: '4' }, { filter: '18' }],
    result = Array.from(
        data.reduce((m, o) => {
            var [key, value] = Object.entries(o)[0],
                item = m.get(key);
        
            return m.set(key, item ? [].concat(item, value) : value);
        }, new Map),
        ([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v })
    );

console.log(Array.from(result));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: A little bit too verbose? care to explain

Answer (score 2):

Just using a for loop:

```
const array = [
    {date_range_one: '2018-03-03+-+2018-05-01'},
    {date_range_two: '2001-11-27+-+2018-05-01'},
    {filter: '1'},
    {filter: '4'},
    {filter: '18'},
];

const set = {}

for (const entry of array) {
  const key = Object.keys(entry)[0];
  const value = entry[key];
  if (set.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    set[key] = [...set[key], value];
  } else {
    set[key] = value;
  }
}

const result = Object.entries(set)
  .map(([key, value]) => ({[key]: value}))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: The OP asked for an array of objects, but you are pushing it into an object. `const result = {}` which should be `const result = new Array();`

Comment: @kunal-mukherjee Thank you for correcting me! I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for this option. There is a little issue while compiling the array from values (set[key] = [...set[key], value];). Spread attribute ... splitting the string if filter are not an single value ({filter: 'some value'},). By removing that 'Spread Attributes' fixes the issue.